# How to access existing user email in devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using ruby on rails with Devise gem to authenticate user. Every time a new user signs with his/her email address, I can see devise is allocating new user ID to that user and registering there email address. Now I want to display a welcome message for all the first time user ( I do not want this message to appear when they login for 2nd or 3rd time). 
To display the message I want to check current_user.email against all the registered email in the user table (logic here is: if the user already exists in the user table then I can safely assume that the user has already visited the website so I prevent the welcome being displayed). I am not sure how to access all the email id's in the table?? also where to do this check. I want this welcome message to be the first thing user sees as soon as there sign in is successful. Can anyone help please.

I tried to use "resource" resource_name" within sessions controller but nothing works. Not sure weather those are even remotely relevant.

```
    # POST /resource/sign_in
    def create       
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      $sign = sign_in_count
      set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)      
    end
```

I am trying to assign sign_in_count for logged in user to a global variable called $sign so that I can use it's value to check if user has signed in for first time or not.

Comment: New user record is created on sign up, not on first sign in. If the user is signed in automatically after signing up you can customize Registrations#create, otherwise Sessions#create. In the latter case check `sign_in_count`, as suggested in the answer

Comment: When I use "sign_in_count" within sessionController # create, I am getting the error: undefined local variable or method `sign_in_count' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x00007f21e4222380> Did you mean? sign_out

Comment: How do you use it? Add code to the question

Comment: @Vasilisa I have added the code as you asked. Pls let me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sign_in_count` is a column in `users` table. Should be:

```
# sessions_controller.rb
def create
  super # just call predefined action 
  set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in) if resource.sign_in_count == 1
end
```

Comment: @Pal happy to help you!

Answer (score 2):

To display a message the first time user logs in your app why not use the sign_in_count ?

This avoids you to get all email addresses in your db to check if it exist already